# Stationary sequence and nonzero probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Suppose I have a two sided stationary sequence of random variables $\ldots,X_{-1},X_0,X_1,\ldots$ such that all finite dimensional joint densities $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ exist. I want to ensure the following:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be events such that $P(\ldots,X_{-1},X_0\in A)>0$ and $P(X_1,X_2,\ldots\in B)>0$, then
>   $$
> P(\ldots,X_{-1},X_0\in A \qquad\text{and}\qquad X_1,X_2,\ldots\in B)>0.
> $$

Is it enough to assume that the finite dimensional joint densities all have full support?